# Call inside app android programmatically

Tags: android

I try to define an application where we can talk. I know that it is possible to open the phone call but I would like to make a call from the app herself.
That I add additional buttons designated for application. Right now this is what I found:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phnum)); 
startActivity(callIntent);
```

But it opens the conversation of the device and I need something I can change.
I interested that by clicking DIAL The call will dial and remain within an application. Since there are other things I would like to take the user from using the application. 
Would appreciate help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The purpose of the `ACTION_CALL` constant is to open the dialer. If you want to do voice communications inside an app without using the device's phone dialer, it's something you would have to implement yourself.

Comment: I searched but did not find, how can you do it?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html

Comment: This is not a SIP case. SIP is for VOIP which is a different case.